# Open a Pdf in IOS App

Tags: html, ios, iphone

I am making a IOS App and i want to open a PDF in div tag of my html file.I have found a code which works well on windows but it is not working in iOS app. In iOS app it just show the image of the first page.

Comment: instead you can show PDF in UIWebView.

Comment: Please checkthis tutorial https://mobiforge.com/design-development/importing-exporting-documents-ios

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: Richard can give me an idea to close a pdf in UIWebView because my only requirement is (1) the user click on the links to show pdf (2) The pdf will render on page (3) their should be a button which closes this pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Open the pdf in Webview and keep a button on top right corner (or anywhere) You want it.. And their you can write code for dismissing the WebView.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"documentName" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

And in Done Button Action Just remove the WebView

Comment: Richard we are working on html app  and code is                                            < a href="some.pdf" >click to view pdf< / a >                                                            it opens the pdf in full screen thats works fine but we also want to close the pdf so that we can return back to page

Comment: How You want To close the Pdf ?  Their must be some button for that . Where you want to keep that?

Comment: yes we should keep button but how to do this i am not able to understand as i am new to ios